# Gitlab ssh timeouts

Tags: ssh, gitlab, proxmox

We have gitlab instance running in LXT container on proxmox server, installed as described at https://about.gitlab.com/install/#debian. The https clonning is disabled for security reasons.

For some reasons the ssh acces sometimes failes with timeout. When this happens every user is affected. The issue resolves itself after a while. Sometimes for a few minutes, sometimes we don't run into it for weeks.
Only the ssh acces is affected, the  browser interface seems ok.
We can see no spike in HW usage on the container (CPU, RAM, traffic, disk IO). There is sufficient free RAM and the CPU utilization is less than 10%. When trying to read the logs on the ritlab instance we see nothing that would help us explain or solve this issue.

Can anyone point us in any direction?